# How to show a notification when data updates in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a chat app and I am using cloud firestore as my database.

In my **User** model, I have an ArrayList of String to store the id of *Chats*. And in my **Chat** model, I have an ArrayList of String to store the *Messages*. now, I want to show a notification when that messages ArrayList updates even when the app is not running. Is there any solution

Comment: Yes there is a way, you can check out Firestore Snapshot Listener documentation.https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#java

Answer (score 1):

for local change you can use this code

```
val docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")
docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
        return@addSnapshotListener
    }

    val source = if (snapshot != null && snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites())
        "Local"
    else
        "Server"

    if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "$source data: ${snapshot.data}")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "$source data: null")
    }
}
```

your listeners will be notified with the new data before the data is sent to the backend.

For better reference you can [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#kotlin+ktx_1)

Comment: but how I can show a notification if the app is close

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

add these lines in your manifest

Comment: <service
            android:name=".FirebaseService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

create services and broadcast receiver for notification

if work please mark right